# Can both gerund or infinitive make it in this case

Tags: gerunds

6. He never remembers 1. _______ his mother a birthday card. It has been so long since he did it that she can't remember ever 2._RECEIVING_one from him

Could it be in 1 **sending**: I know the solution is to send but I  think sending could make it too because he did send... may be  a long time ago but he did it.

I know the difference between "remember to" or "remember gerund" but in this particular case I think both can fit. I don't see a real difference.

https://www.dailystep.com/en/blog/remember-and-forget-gerund-or-infinitive-how-does-the-meaning-change

Comment: It might help to note that *I will remember **to do** it* is a perfectly natural way of saying *I know I must do it, and **I will not forget***. For which the Past Tense version is *I **remembered / did remember** to do it* (I didn't forget) is also natural. But Present Tense + Infinitive *(I remember **to do** it)* and Future + Continuous *(I **will remember** doing it)* are extremely unlikely forms that would only occur in "unusual" contexts. With the infinitive, what's remembered is the ***need*** to act; with the continuous, what's remembered is *the (past) act of **doing it***.

Comment: so sending is better as it is a present tense

Comment: *He didn't remember **to send** her a card* means he forgot that he was supposed to send her a card (consequently, *he didn't send it*). But *He didn't remember **sending** her a card* means he ***has no recollection*** of doing that. Maybe he ***did*** send it, but subsequently forgot what he did; OR maybe he never sent it anyway, which explains why he has no memory of doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate, but you might find [*Why is “He knows **to swim**” incorrect?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31852/why-is-he-knows-to-swim-incorrect) (Spoiler alert: It's ***not*** "incorrect"; it just has a different meaning to *He knows **swimming***).